# Regex not working and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<span style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">LG ha tolto i veli al nuovo&nbsp;LG Chocolate, nome in codice <strong>BL40</strong>, un cellulare dalla forma insolita e dai contenuti tecnologici molto avanzati.&nbsp;A prima vista colpisce subito l'imponente <strong>schermo LCD da&nbsp;4 pollici&nbsp;e risoluzione di 800x345 pixel</strong>, che corrispondono a un f<strong>ormato di&nbsp;21:9</strong>. Questo rapporto d'aspetto permette di vedere a tutto schermo i film in questo formato, ma non solo: a beneficiarne è infatti anche la navigazione sui siti Internet. Grazie poi alla funzionalità&nbsp;Dual Screen UI&nbsp;è possibile visualizzare contemporaneamente sullo schermo due tipi di contenuti differenti.</span>
```

I'm using regular expression to strip the span. I must strip the span with the exact match, because I'm processing about 12.000 document.

I'm using:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/<span style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">(.*?)<\/span>/s', '<p>$1</p>',$string);
```

It doesn't work, I try also with Rubular. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the parenthesis’s:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/<span style="color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\); font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">(.*?)<\/span>/s', '<p>$1</p>',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error is not escaping your parens in `color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\);`.  if you do that, your regex will match

http://rubular.com/r/b7iBT5Apd6

Comment: I escaped the parens now but my preg_replace is not working :/